# String concatenation in loop makes result empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

There is a string concatenation of unicode strings in a loop:

```
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
    $result .= $post['blah']
}
```

At some point in the middle of the loop $result becomes empty and remains empty despite appending more strings. What confuses me even more is it has length > 0 and increasing on adding more strings. What can be causing it?

**Update**

I forgot to mention that I do initialise $result like this

```
$result = '';
```

Each string contains html and also may have some special characters. I suspect some of the characters is throwing php string off, making it look empty, but have length.

Comment: Have you initialized `$result` outside the loop?

Comment: have you initialize the `$result` variable before foreach?

Comment: print result after every loop you will get the answer. Add `echo $result;` after appending.

Comment: Please see the update

Answer (score 0):

Try, rather than appending to a string, using an array

```
$tmp=array();
foreach( $posts as $i => $post )$tmp[$i]=$post['blah'];

print_r( $tmp );
```

You should then be able to see more clearly what is happening perhaps and then you can `implode`

```
$tmp=array_filter( $tmp );
echo implode(' ',$tmp );
```

Answer (score 0):

$result exists within the scope of the loop, so every iteration through the loop causes $result to be re initialized, before executing your concatenation code.

Declare $result outside the loop, before it begins.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for my problem. It seems that it's a encoding problem, some of the strings might be wrongly detected as non utf-8. What worked for me is forcing each string to utf-8.

```
$result = '';
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $result .= iconv( 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $item);
}
```